# Why does this unit test say my directory doesn't exist when it does?

Tags: java, file, getfiles

This code

```
URL listofFiles = this.getClass().getResource("someDir");
File f = new File(listofFiles.toString());
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

runs in a JUnit unit test in a Tomcat webserver environment.

The URL that's returned is most definitely valid. I've gone into the Finder in OS X, performed a "Go to Directory," pasted in the value of `listofFiles` and seen all my files in the directory.

Why is `listFiles()` returning null?

Comment: You should check that: call `f.exists()` and `f.isDirectory()` to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Javadoc for `File.listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29):

> **Returns:**
>   An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

The fact that you are getting a `null` return value indicates that the path you are passing into the File constructor does not point to a directory.

I suspect that passing the result of `URL.toString()` to the File constructor is building a path that is not what you think it is. Instead, try something like

```
File f = new File(listofFiles.toURI());
```

In addition, you might want to log the value of `f.getAbsolutePath()` to make sure that the path being read is the same as what you expect.

Comment: It looks like to me the getClass() method is returning a bad value because something is "out of sync". I have to rebuild my project semi-frequently (2 or 3 times a day while working on this) and it just works afterwards. We're using Tomcat if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

The File constructor with a String expects a path, not (the toString of) a URL.

Use a different constructor, for example `new File(listofFiles.toURI())`. Or give it a path: `new File(listofFiles.getPath())`.

Update: Or (as ugly as this may seem) [try both File constructors](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/04/how_to_convert.html), as Java-guru Kohsuke Kawaguchi suggests.

> If only we had File(URL) constructor...